# PIL - how to insert an index, or subscript, into text?

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

Like this:
[image]

Calculating coordinates looks not so good, maybe there is a better way?

This code works fine ([image]), but it's complicated always calculate where to place index for each letter.

```
image = Image.new('I', (300, 100), "white").convert('RGBA')
font = ImageFont.truetype(font=r"C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf", size=39)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image, 'RGBA')

draw.text((10, 10), "P", fill="black", font=font, align="center")

font = ImageFont.truetype(font=r"C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf", size=20)
draw.text((25, 35), "2", fill="black", font=font, align="center")

image.save(output_folder + 'test.png')
```

Comment: What do you mean with "calculating coordinates" looks not so good? What have you done now and what are you expecting?

Comment: @physicalattraction, added code

Answer (score 3):

One possibility for you might be to use **ImageMagick** which understands **Pango Markup Language** - which looks kind of like HTML.

So, at the command-line you could run this:

```
convert -background white pango:'<span size="49152">Formula: <b>2P<sub><small><small>2</small></small></sub>O<sub><small><small>5</small></small></sub></b></span>' formula.png
```

which produces this PNG file:

[image]

Change to `-background none` to write on a piece of transparent canvas if you want to preserve whatever is underneath the text in your original image.

You can also put all the markup in a separate text file, called say `"pango.txt"` like this:

```
<span size="49152">Formula: <b>2P<sub><small><small>2</small></small></sub>O<sub><small><small>5</small></small></sub></b></span>
```

and pass that into **ImageMagick** like this:

```
convert pango:@pango.txt result.png
```

---

You could shell out and do this using:

```
subprocess.call()
```

Then you can easily load the resultant image and composite/paste it in where you want it - that would take about 3 lines of Python that you could put in a function.

---

Here is a further example of an image generated with **Pango** by Anthony Thyssen so you can see some of the possibilities:

[image]

There is loads of further information on **Pango** by Anthony [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#pango_markup).

---

Note that there are also **Python** bindings for **ImageMagick** but I am not very familiar with them, but that may be cleaner than shelling out.

**Keywords**: Pango, PIL, Pillow, Python, markup, subscript, superscript, formula, chemical formulae, ImageMagick, image, image processing, SGML, HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works, but for me it seems insert indexes using code from question is the same complicated as using ImageMagick.

Comment: Cool - I understand, it was just an idea for getting a subscript. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this sort of thing using Mathtext in Matplotlib:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.axes([0.025, 0.025, 0.95, 0.95])

# Some formula with superscripts, subscripts, square roots, fractions and integrals
eq    = r"$ 2P_2 O_5 + H^{2j}$"
size  = 50
x,y   = 0.5, 0.5
alpha = 1
params = {'mathtext.default': 'regular' }
plt.rcParams.update(params)
plt.text(x, y, eq, ha='center', va='center', color="#11557c", alpha=alpha,
         transform=plt.gca().transAxes, fontsize=size, clip_on=True)

# Suppress ticks
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

# Save on transparent background
plt.savefig('result.png', transparent=True)
```

[image]

You can also save the output in a memory buffer (without going to disk) and then use that in your PIL-based image processing.

Note that I have explicitly named and assigned all the parameters (`x`, `y`, `size` and `alpha`) so you can play with them and that makes the code look longer and more complicated than it actually is.

**Keywords**: Python, PIL, Pillow, maths, mathematical symbols, formula with superscripts, subscripts, square roots, fractions and integrals.