# PIL Writing Text on Image Using Escape Sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

```
`from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

image = Image.new('RGB', (950, 250), color=(255, 255, 255))
TEXT = 'You are a wondeful \033[32mperson.'
font_size = 50
font_type = "SourceCodePro-Bold.ttf"
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im=image)
font = ImageFont.truetype(font_type, font_size)
draw.multiline_text((int(950 / 2), int(250 / 2)), text=TEXT, font=font,fill=(0, 0, 0), anchor='mm')
image.show()`
```

I tried to print text on an image using some escape sequence "\033[32m" using PIL (Pillow).

I was expecting the below output image

**What I want**
[image: expectation]

**What I'm getting**
[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2xdC.png)]

So anybody have any idea that how to get the desired result then it'll be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this procedure will not work yet. It's possible by changing the text position . if you want i can give a static solution. for this text

Comment: please share your solution.

Comment: please check on answer.. I have given the solution.. you can modify your code in this logic. thanks

Comment: The sequence you are using is an *"ANSI Escape Sequence"* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code and they are only really used for controlling text colour and cursor position on ***terminals*** rather than in image processing.

Comment: Then Mark do you have any better solution for this ?

Comment: The nearest I know of is **Pango** which you can certainly do with **ImageMagick** just in the shell, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51963371/2836621 I have not tried it with `wand` the ctypes binding of ImageMagick to Python https://pypi.org/project/Wand/

Comment: If it is in `wand` I guess you'd need to open a pseudo-image prefixed `pango:` as per examples here https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.10/guide/read.html#open-a-pseudo-image

Comment: Thank you very much Mark for your time & effort. Let me try those.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this one and change the position of text. i think this logic will help you. thanks**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
image = Image.new('RGB', (950, 250), "white")
text1 = "You are a wondeful"
text2="Person"
font_size = 100
font_type = "SourceCodePro-Bold.ttf"
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im=image)
font = ImageFont.load_default()
draw.multiline_text((int(950 / 2), int(250 / 2)), text=text1, font=font,fill ="black",anchor='mm')
draw.multiline_text((int(1180 / 2), int(250 / 2)), text=text2, font=font,fill = "green",anchor='mm')
image.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in your case you are hard coding the  x position of text2. but suppose if the length of text1 changes then i have to change the x position of text2. my goal is to automate the whole process.